# Typescript Error Trying to Pass children to forwardHref

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have the following component:

```js
'use client';

import NextLink, { LinkProps } from 'next/link';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

import { onStart } from '../events';
import { shouldTriggerStartEvent } from './should-trigger-start-event';

export const Link = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>(function Link(
    { onClick, ...rest },
    ref,
) {
    return (
        <NextLink
            onClick={event => {
                linkClicked(event);
                if (onClick) onClick(event);
            }}
            {...rest}
            ref={ref}
        />
    );
});

export function linkClicked(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) {
    const anchorElement = event.currentTarget as HTMLAnchorElement;
    const { href } = anchorElement;
    if (href || href.startsWith('/')) {
        if (shouldTriggerStartEvent(href, event)) onStart();
    }
}
```

I'm passing `LinkProps` as the second argument to `forwardHref` generic, but I get a type error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string | UrlObject; as?: string | UrlObject | undefined; replace?: boolean | undefined; scroll?: boolean | undefined; ... 7 more ...; onClick?: MouseEventHandler<...> | undefined; } & RefAttributes<...>'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string | UrlObject; as?: string | UrlObject | undefined; replace?: boolean | undefined; scroll?: boolean | undefined; ... 7 more ...; onClick?: MouseEventHandler<...> | undefined; } & RefAttributes<...>'.
```

How do I properly apply the NextLink props? FYI: this is part of a package I maintain called `nextjs13-progress`. Please fork if you would prefer.

INFO: this only recently occurred after updating. I think its because I upgrade to Typescript 5.